# Asp.net Javascript runat server error: not a valid virtual path

Tags: javascript, asp.net, runatserver

Hello i want to include a javascript in my page like this:

```
   <script runat="server" id="js_common_FluidInput" type="text/javascript" src="https://file.domain.com/Script/Common/FluidInput.js"></script>
```

but i get this error:

> https:/file.domain.com/Script/Common/FluidInput.js' is not a valid virtual path.

i've found this solution but i really hope there will be a better one:

```
       <% #if DEBUG %>
<script type="text/javascript src="https://file.domain.com/Script/Common/FluidInput.js"></script><% #else %><asp:literal runat="server" id="jsAncor" ></literal><% #endif %>
```

Comment: you dont need  runat="server" id="js_common_FluidInput". please delete these and build....

Comment: can you use `runat` inside a `JavaScript` `<script>`tag ?

Comment: i need to run this at server because i've to made some url trasformation server side

Answer (score 0):

ayilmaz was right, for some reason when you user runat="server" you cant use full path, only relative.

on my other  tags with relative paths it was ok to use runat="server"